# In-App purchase product not found

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, identifier

I'm trying to test in-app purchases in demo app. But when I'm press "Buy" button, message "Product not found: com.company.inappdemo.test" appears.

I'm sure that Bundle ID and Product ID is right. What else can be wrong and cause an error?

P.S. Link to guide, that I used as an example.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial

---

Solution >>>

**Contract, tax and banking should be filled and approved to use any in-app purchase operations, including testing.**

Comment: The error you quoted references 'com.company.inappdemo.test' (which is different from your Bundle ID). Are you sure that's all correct?

Comment: There was "com.konstantincherkasov.inappdemo.test" in my code, just forgot to change the screenshot. I'm sure, that bundle ID and product ID is correct.

Comment: Did you try all of the troubleshooting steps in that link you gave?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it did not work. I think, that the problem cause is banking update is still in progress. So I should wait to find out it exactly.

Comment: Your solution is working. Add it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

It works only with the original device. Try testing the same on device not on simulator